# Filter array in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

I have a material with a certain ID number and an array of products that contain an array of materials they consist of. I need to filter out all the products that include that specific material (all the products that have that ID number inside their materials array). 
Is there a prompt way to do that with ES6 syntax?

E.g

````
const myMaterialId = 100

const productsArray = [
  {
    name: products,
    materials: [
      {id: 100, amount: 30},
      {id: 102, amount: 20},
    ],
  },
  {
    name: product2,
    materials: [
      {id: 115, amount: 25},
      {id: 120, amount: 50},
    ],
  },
  {
    name: product2,
    materials: [
      {id: 100, amount: 35},
      {id: 120, amount: 50},
      {id: 150, amount: 10},
    ],
  }
];```
````

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: You first need to know how to ask a question [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Seeing a data structure. But not a coding attempt?

Comment: I apologize for not posting my attempts. I was trying to apply filter method to the array twice and would get all the items. As it turned out I needed to use filter and then find method.  My code example from the project below                                                                                                     
 `let productsFiltered = props.products.filter((product) =>
    product.activeMaterials.filter(
      (material) => material.activeMaterial === id
    ),
  );`

Comment: do you have a wanted result? please edit the question with your attempt, the wanted result and why your result does not match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```
var filteredProductsArray = productsArray.filter(product => product.materials.filter(material => material.id === myMaterialId).length > 0);
```

This will filter all products by filtering their materials to see if the materials array has a material with your material id.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/8r31zdav/ u can use filter and find method

```
 var result= productsArray.filter(x=>x.materials.find(y=>y.id==myMaterialId));
```

and also your object is invalid. value of name attribute is string so u need to write it in ""

```
const productsArray = [
  {
    name: "products",
    materials: [
      {id: 100, amount: 30},
      {id: 102, amount: 20},
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "product3",
    materials: [
      {id: 115, amount: 25},
      {id: 120, amount: 50},
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "product2",
    materials: [
      {id: 100, amount: 35},
      {id: 120, amount: 50},
      {id: 150, amount: 10},
    ],
  }
];
```